# Are the SObjects in a trigger execution always the result of DML from a single user?

Tags: trigger

I realised recently that I was unsure if:

1. SObjects in Triggers are always the result of a single user performing a DML operation.
2. Or whether, if 2 or more users happened to save a record at exactly the same time, that could result in all their records appearing in the same trigger.

Does anyone know the answer to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard `SObject` trigger invocations are directly related to a DML operation within a given transaction and this is necessarily in the context of a single user since that is the way that transactions work (there is a contextual user). I.e. the trigger is called with records modified in that one DML operation in that transaction, and you don't get records from other DML operations on other transactions mixed in.

This segregation is essential, otherwise it would be impossible to implement transactional rollback or the DML all-or-nothing handling. See [Apex Transactions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm) documentation for more info on those.

Note that trigger-based Platform Event subscribers behave differently, receiving events from multiple up-stream transactions. This is the case because these event records go into a queue, rather than into the database, and are processed in a different transaction to the one where they were published.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I appreciate your post. Nicely explained.